# Why doesn't dot product x@A work if x is a pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, vector, dot-product

- `A` is a 5x5 square matrix **pandas DataFrame**
- `x` is a 5 (one-dimensional) vector **pandas Series**

`x@A` returns error `ValueError: matrices are not aligned` even though they clearly  both meet the requirement for dot product multiplication, having the same outer-dimension, 5.

whereas `x.values @ A` works, returning the expected scalar, simply because `x` has been changed from a pandas Series to a `numpy` array

Why is the dot symbol `@` so picky with pandas?

Comment: kindly provide sample data with expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

> In addition, the column names of DataFrame and the **index of other must
> contain the same values**, as they will be aligned prior to the
> multiplication.

So the error is not about dimensions but rather about non-matching indices. See the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], columns=list('ab'))
s = pd.Series([5,6])

# df @ s                                      # --> doesn't work
print(df.values @ s)                          # --> works because no column names involved
print(df.rename({'a':0, 'b':1}, axis=1) @ s)  # --> works because indices match
```

or the other way round

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], index=list('ab'))
s = pd.Series([5,6])

# s @ df                             # --> doesn't work
print(s @ df.values)                 # --> works because no column names involved
print(s @ df.reset_index(drop=True)) # --> works because indices match
```